# Simple HTML Dom save file with Cron Job once a day, then access that saved file

Tags: php, parsing, caching, dom

I am using SimpleHTMLDom to get some info off of a RSS feed. This data is only updated once a day around 7am. I would like to use the feature $html->save('result.htm'); Then have my page just load the result.htm file instead of running the parse each time I look at the page.

I guess I am wondering, would this be a good idea? Would it really speed the page load time up that much? Would using a cache be similar or maybe better?

([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517489/simple-html-dom-caching) almost address this)

Answer (score 1):

yes, it would be a good idea and you couldn't get any faster (unless you load the page to webserver memory and serve it from there).

just extend the cronjob you already have to process the data with SimpleHTMLDom and save the html it produced at 7am. Then keep serving that file until the next morning.

Just make sure you create a tmp-file first (result.tmp.html) the next morning and only do the move/rename once the cronjob finishes.

i am not sure i told you anything you didn't know already...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is good to know about the temp file.