# Scraping much data from different URLs with simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, performance, dom

i basically want to do exactly something like this: [Simple Html DOM Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517489/simple-html-dom-caching)

i got everything to work so far, but now i'm getting the following error because i scrape many sites (6 at the moment, i want up to 25 sites):

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes)
```

i'm a php newbie =/...so, how can i "serialize" the scraping process step by step that my memory don't give up? :-)

code sample:

```
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// retrieve and find contents
$html0 = file_get_html('http://www.site.com/');
foreach($html0->find('#id') as $aktuelle_spiele);

file_put_contents("cache/cache0.html",$aktuelle_spiele);
```

thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Up teh memory limit....it seems you have only 32 mb of memory limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run a memory increase at the start of your script.

Like this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Answer (score 3):

In your php.ini, change this line:

memory_limit = 32M

With this one:

memory_limit = 256M //or another greater value

Or add this piece of code at the start of every php script that use simple_html_dom:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); //or a greater value
```

Comment: @ThomasVeit, you can run a memory increase at the start of your script. Like this: ini_set('memory_limit', '128M')

Comment: mhhh, my hoster does not allow more than 32M memory... someone has another idea to reduce my script memory?

Comment: I thought you have your own server...you can add the line proposed by @Luigi and the start of every script that use simple html dom php

Comment: @ThomasVeit. I have pasted my comment as an answer. Sorry Robert. +1